# CSS grid how to use auto-fit for set number of columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I have set the grid with 2 columns, one has the set width of `350px`, and the other takes the rest of the space:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">
  <div class="item2"> 
</div>
```

The styling of the container for this two elements looks like this:

```
container: {
    padding: 25,
    display: 'grid',
    gridColumnGap: '80px',
    gridTemplateColumns: 'auto 350px',
    margin: '64px auto',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    maxWidth: '1440px',
  },
```

How can I make this set up responsive, so that when there is not enough screen width, one item goes below other?

Comment: media query or switch to flexbox which more suitable here

Answer (score -1):

Use media queries.

```
@media (max-width:576px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```